# Extract attribute's value with XPath in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xslt, lxml

I have the HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0 10px 0 60px;">
<img src="/files/39.jpg" width="64" height="64">
</td>
<td align="left" valign="middle"><h1>30 Rock</h1></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using Python and LXML I need to extract the value from the attribute `src` of the `<img>` element. Here's what I've tried:

```
import lxml.html
import urllib

# make HTTP request to site
page = urllib.urlopen("http://my.url.com")
# read the downloaded page
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page.read())

txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/img')
```

When I print `txt1` I get the empty list only `[]`. How can I correct this?

Comment: Use `img/@src`. As for why you get the empty list, that's to be expected if this is the actual HTML you're parsing, because it doesn't match the XPath.

Comment: Thanks for advice. This is just a cut from HTML-doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//img/@src
```

Selects the `src` attributes of all `img` elements in the entire input XML document

Comment: The description is incorrect: `//img/@src` will select the `src` attributes of all `img` elements in the entire input XML document. If you want to limit the selection to descendants  of the context node, you need to use `.//img/@src`.